# SQL Server - Efficient way of grouping values by the first date they happened before they happen again

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure the title describes exactly what I want to do very well, but here's a working example which I need to speed up...

```
/*
Aim:
2018-01-01, 1
2018-09-01, 2
2019-01-01, 1
2019-04-01, 3
2020-04-01, 1
2020-09-01, 2
2021-01-01, 1
*/

;WITH temp (ID, GroupID, Date, Value) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 1, CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (2, 1, CAST('2018-04-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (3, 1, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE), 2),
        (4, 1, CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (5, 1, CAST('2019-04-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (6, 1, CAST('2019-09-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (7, 1, CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (8, 1, CAST('2020-04-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (9, 1, CAST('2020-09-01' AS DATE), 2),
        (10, 1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (11, 2, CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (12, 2, CAST('2018-04-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (13, 2, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE), 2),
        (14, 2, CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (15, 2, CAST('2019-04-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (16, 2, CAST('2019-09-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (17, 2, CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE), 3),
        (18, 2, CAST('2020-04-01' AS DATE), 1),
        (19, 2, CAST('2020-09-01' AS DATE), 2),
        (20, 2, CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE), 1)
    ) AS X(ID, GroupID, Date, Value)
)
select t1.* from temp t1
left join temp t2 on t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID
    and t1.Value = t2.Value
    and t2.Date < t1.Date
    and not exists (
        select * 
        from temp t3 
        where t1.groupID = t3.GroupID 
            and t3.Value != t1.Value 
            and t3.Date between t2.Date and t1.Date
    )
where t2.ID is null
order by t1.GroupID asc, t1.Date asc
```

This is returning the results that I want, but when I use real data the query is really slow. It seems to be the NOT EXISTS check which is taking so long

For each GroupID I want to select the earliest Date for each Value until the next Value happens and I'm sure there must be a better/faster way of doing this, but can't think of one at the minute.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Please try to explain the logic and show the result set for the data you have provided.

Comment: This seems like a gaps and islands type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an example of a groups-and-islands problem.  In this case, the best solution is to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by groupid order by date) as prev_value
      from temp t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3389e7bb75fb2ead7c4c8c20611f3b52) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Suspected I wanted to use a Partition in some way, but I'd never seen the lag function before - need to do some reading on that. Looks to be doing exactly what I wanted though. Thanks!